# Convergence issues with linear mixed effects models with statsmodels

Tags: statsmodels

I have convergence issues for a mixed effects linear model. I would like to dig what is happening during the optimization. Is there a way to get the iteration log? The best I can do now is get a summary of the optimization by setting disp=True

mdf = md.fit(full_output=True,reml=True,method ='cg',disp=True)

which gives me

Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 2.989371
         Iterations: 5
         Function evaluations: 73
         Gradient evaluations: 62

Thanks

UPDATE: this is not answering my question but with a different solver, I managed to get some convergence. However, this is raising another question. I would expect the score, i.e., the gradient of the log-likehood function, to be small and for my example, this is not the case. Hence, another question is:

what can be trusted? Intituively, my answer would be the score

Comment: I won't know the answer to you question. But have you tried alternative methods for fitting, other than 'cg'?

Comment: I did: 'lbfgs' and 'bfgs'. I am getting convergence in some cases. I would like still like to be able to dig a little deeper though